# How To Parse Maven Dependencies With Or Without Versions Declared Using Notepad++

Tags: regex, maven, notepad++

I'm trying to parse a list of maven dependencies and display it in a simpler format. Specifically I'm trying to convert the standard maven xml of:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>groupId1</groupId>
        <artifactId>artifactId1</artifactId>
        <version>version1</version>
    </dependency>
```

To something like this:

```
groupId1:artifactId1:version1
```

The poms I'm working with are sorted by sortpom-maven-plugin, so I can assume the order to always be groupId, artifactId, version; but I can't assume the version will always be there, or that there won't be other configurations for the dependency.

That means something like the following could be possible:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>groupId1</groupId>
        <artifactId>artifactId1</artifactId>
        <version>version1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>groupId2</groupId>
        <artifactId>artifactId2</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>groupId3</groupId>
        <artifactId>artifactId3</artifactId>
        <version>version3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>groupId4</groupId>
        <artifactId>artifactId4</artifactId>
        <version>version4</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>groupId4</groupId>
                <artifactId>artifactId4</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

I have been using Notepad++ to try and parse these dependencies with regular expressions, and my best effort has come up with the following:

With **Search Mode** set to **Regular Expression** and **match newlines** selected I search for the following:

```
.*?<dependency>.*?<groupId>(.*?)</groupId>.*?<artifactId>(.*?)</artifactId>.*?<version>(.*?)</version>.*?</dependency>.*?\R*
```

and replace with:

```
\1:\2:\3
```

Unfortunately this does not cover the case of an omitted version, so the following

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>groupId2</groupId>
        <artifactId>artifactId2</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>groupId3</groupId>
        <artifactId>artifactId3</artifactId>
        <version>version3</version>
    </dependency>
```

Would be transformed to:

```
groupId1:artifactId1:version2
```

When ideally I would like to see it converted to something like this:

```
groupId1:artifactId1
groupId2:artifactId2:version2
```

Would anyone have suggestions on improving my regular expression? It doesn't have to be a single regular express either. If running sequential expressions will ultimately transform the dependencies into the desired format that's ok.

Answer (score 3):

#### 1st replacement

Find what:

```
<([^>]+)>([^<]+)</\1>(?:(?!\s*</)\s*)?
```

Replace with:

```
\2:
```

- That will result in *almost* what you want: `groupId1:artifactId1:version1:`

#### 2nd replacement

To remove the trailing "`:`", Find what:

```
:\s*?$
```

Replace with:

```
{leave empty}
```